# Openstack instance is unreachable

Tags: xenserver, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am facing the following issue with my new Openstack installation.
The installation is a little bit weird and to elaborate more, I have a controller and a compute node running as VMs in XenServer.

The compute node has nested virtualization enabled and uses qemu in order to provision VMs.
I have a provider flat network that has a public range of IPs and VMs use this network.

I am able to create instances and access them via console, but I can't ping them or ssh even if they have public IPs.

I am not very familiar with Xen Server, is there any configuration that is needed (bridges, promisc mode, etc)?

Comment: What deployment do you use ? I have similar problem before and solved by this line : https://gist.github.com/gilangvperdana/e74b3536c0c8786c68cb3ed51e4acbd2#what-to-do-when-restarting-openstack-cluster

Comment: I did the installation using this
https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are accessing the console through Horizon. Since you are able to spin up instances and can access console. I do not think its Xenserver. Have you checked your default security group rules to ensure you are allowing/opening the ports for ICMP and connections to port 22/SSH?

Comment: Yes I checked the security group. It is ok